# Прикрепление к экрану какой-либо надписи в LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

На данный момент я пишу игру на LibGDX.
И у меня есть вот такой код:

```
@Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
        batch.begin();
        Draw.draw();
        MainScreen.player.draw();
        TextManager.displayMessage("FPS: "+ Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(), true, false, false, false);
        PlayerControl.update();
        CamControl.update();
        UI.drawCurrentBlock();
        batch.end();
    }
```

Проблема в том, что надпись-счетчик fps, который реализуется при помощи TextManager, не "прикреплен" к экрану. Он попросту стоит на месте на поле игры. Мне же нужно, чтобы он следовал за игроком/камерой. Помогите реализовать данный аспект.

```
package aof.loaders;

import aof.screens.MainScreen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout;

public class TextManager {

    static BitmapFont font;
    static float width, height;

    public static void initialize(float width,float height){

        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/font.fnt"));
        TextManager.width = width;
        TextManager.height = height;

        font.getData().scaleX = MainScreen.aspectRatio * 1.5f;
        font.getData().scaleY = 1;
        Log.info(font.getData().scaleY);

    }

    public static void displayMessage(String text, float x, float y){

        GlyphLayout glyphLayout = new GlyphLayout();
        glyphLayout.setText(font, text);

        font.draw(MainScreen.batch, glyphLayout, x, y);
    }

    public static void displayMessage(String text, boolean left, boolean right, boolean top, boolean bottom){
        float x = (float) MainScreen.WIDTH/2, y = (float) MainScreen.HEIGHT/2;
        if(left) x = 0;
        if(bottom) y = 20;
        if(right) x = MainScreen.WIDTH-50;
        if(top) y = MainScreen.HEIGHT-20;
        displayMessage(text, x, y);
    }

    public static void dispose() {
        font.dispose();
    }
}
```

Код TextManager.

Пробовал решить данную проблему посредством прикрепления надписи непосредственно к координатам камеры. Однако, в этом случае, текст и/или картинка подергивается. То есть, не статичны.

Comment: Покажите ваш TextManager, скорее всего там камера не та.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял внутри TextManager обычный Label. Тогда можно использовать еще один SpriteBatch, либо перемещать Label вместе с камерой. Позицию камеры можно получить так OrthographicCamera.position.

Comment: Возможно, старый вопрос, и мне не ответят, но все же. Можете привести код вашей идеи?

Comment: Label.setPosition(OrthographicCamera.position.x, OrthographicCamera.position.y); и поместить этот код в render()